# trying to fix my tabs when loading in https

Tags: javascript, php, html, web

hi to all i was wondering if someone could help me im trying to figure out tabs example

Sign Up this will only work on http://
when its on https:// it doesn't work i'm choosing https:// because more secure as i haven't found a way to secure http:// and its not my server so i don't have the key for

my login page now http://kuiq.ml/modz/
https://kuiq.ml/modz/

Comment: You need to learn how to use your browsers debugging tools. Your image path is wrong.

Comment: Image path returns a 404

Comment: i looked as well but its still doing the same thing

Answer (score 1):

On Browser tool i see Your bacground path is

```
background-image: url(/lake-lucerne-3840x2400-switzerland-landscape-lake-mountain-4k-15261.jpg);
```

But it should be like this

```
background-image: url(../lake-lucerne-3840x2400-switzerland-landscape-lake-mountain-4k-15261.jpg);
```

See Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the source code hosted at the URL you provided, I can see this CSS code for your `body` tag :

```
body {
  width: auto%;
  height: auto%;
  background-image: url("/lake-lucerne-3840x2400-switzerland-landscape-lake-mountain-4k-15261.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}
```

Moreover, the Devtools console showed the following error : `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) : lake-lucerne-3840x2400-switzerland-landscape-lake-mountain-4k-15261.jpg`

It seems like you did not upload the background image of your `body` to your web host.

This is why the image is not displayed.

Comment: thanks guys i thought i did change it from when i copied them thank you is there a way to make the board of the box a bit smaller in width background boarder of the login section